# Codehinting/Code completion PHPStorm

Tags: php, plugins, phpstorm

As i started my PhpStorm my codehinting for php/js/... doesn't work anymore. Only HTML and CSS seems to be working. Pretty annoying and i can't find a way to fix it. Someone that had the same problem with phpstorm? if so, share please? A friend of mine had the same problem a year ago, but never fixed it (and stopped developing) so that ain't an answer..

No jibberjabber about go to your preferences etc etc, everything is ok there.

Comment: Version ? `Ctrl + Space` is doing something ? Plateform ? Why you don't try on their support forum ???

Comment: `File` | `Invalidate Caches`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At Dev: ctrl space didn't do anything (ofcourse).

Fixed it by installing 3 older versions and 2 beta's. Updating one of those seems to fix it. Very weird tho.